# SchemaCrawler db2 plugin not found

Tags: db2, schemacrawler

I have the plugin following in my gradle.build:

```
   implementation 'us.fatehi:schemacrawler-db2:16.19.10'
```

But  getting following exception message:

INFO: Not using any SchemaCrawler database plugin
InternalRuntimeException: Add the SchemaCrawler database plugin for  to the CLASSPATH

Is that correct plugin or am I missing something ?

Catalog is get in following way:

```
DB2SimpleDataSource ds = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
ds.set...
DatabaseConnectionSource databaseConnectionSource = DatabaseConnectionSources.fromDataSource( ds);
Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(databaseConnectionSource, options);
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct - add a dependency in Gradle. To fully debug, please attach the complete logs after turning logging on.